# Why is a filesystem type ext3/ext4 simultaneously?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, ext3

My root directory looks like that:

[image]

When I installed Ubuntu I create partition as `ext4`, but now it shows:

> Filesystem type:ext3/ext4.

Another thing is that the pie chart shows three chart and indicator for two colors and in contents:

> Contents: ...(some contents unreadable)

Why?

Comment: If you're creating this chart as a regular (non-root) user, you won't be able to count all the files because you can't look into some system directories, other users' home directories, etc.

Comment: @Ulrich I also able to see the system directories. You see that I up the pic which is my root dir's.

Answer (score 4):

The tool shows the partition as ext3/ext4 because, although ext4 is an improvement over ext3 (increased max file size, increased filesystem size, etc.) they are fully compatible and you can mount an ext3 filesystem as ext4. So it makes sense to show it as ext3/ext4.

The tool also displays "Contents: ...(some contents unreadable)" because, as @UlrichSchwarz wrote in the comments, you ran it as an unprivileged user, so it isn't able to count all the files to which your user has no access: other users' homedirs, some system directories which allow only access to the root user, etc.